# email attatchment winds up being 0,0 kb

Tags: vb.net, email, stream

Im making an emailng function and all works like a charm LOCALLY.
But when i take it to the webserver the email attatchment is 0,0kb.. i figured it has something to do with the stream but i doesnt get any error-messages so its hard to tell.
I cant use the stream on my server?
Heres the code:

```
 If FileUpload1.HasFile = True Then
            Dim tempFileName As String() = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName.Split("\"c)
            Dim emailAttach As New Attachment(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream, tempFileName(tempFileName.Length - 1))

            message.Attachments.Add(emailAttach)
            emailAttach.Dispose()
        End If
```

Tried several things but cant find out why there is a problem

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
message.Attachments.Add(New Attachment(FileUpload1.FileContent, tempFileName(tempFileName.Length - 1), FileFileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType)
```

Remarks:

1. I'm using the [FileContent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.filecontent.aspx) property of the `FileUpload` control (although it seems that it's just an alias to `PostedFile.InputStream`).
2. I'm specifying the MIME type of the file (third parameter of the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ds708xx.aspx)).

Also the problem might be because you make a call to [Dispose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144637.aspx) method which (according to Reflector) closes the input stream.

Comment: Im checking it out atm, but got another error wich seems completely random :S ill get back to you